# Why won't MS Outlook Dial in keyboard shortcut work?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-outlook-2010

Can someone please help me figure out why the short cut to dial a number <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> won't work?

I have tried everything but can't get it to work.

Comment: Post a screenshot of the window you are pressing this shortcut on.  I have verified the shortcut works.  So you either have an add-on that disabled it or you are pressing it on the wrong screen.  Mask out the contact information, of the contact, in the screenshot when you post the url to it.

Comment: Can you show me how to post a screenshot on this site?

Comment: How do I determine if a add-on disabled it?

Comment: Starting Outlook without any add-ons would be a good start.

Comment: Ramhound, I disable every single add-in but it still wouldn't work. Anymore thoughts? Cheers